# Robot Framework, control process in task manager

Tags: process, pycharm, operating-system, robotframework

I have to control the process (in task manager) opened by an external application in windows.

the only result I got was closing them with the pid:

```
${rc_code}    ${output}    Run And Return Rc And Output    taskkill /PID ${PID} /F /T
Run Keyword If    '${rc_code}' != '0'    Log    There was error during termination of process    WARN
```

but I want to check them by name or ${CURDIR}

Comment: taskkill /IM ${process_name_here} /F ?